# Ajax request's life cycle?

Tags: ajax

After launching an ajax request in a Web page, The Page windows was closed before the ajax response returned. Ajax request will normally run in the background to the end?The callback function will be executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No the Ajax call is aborted when the page is closed.

If the http request got out, than the server will get it. But the response will not be read/handled.

If the http request was still being initialized, then the call will not be sent.

There is no real way to ensure that the ajax call would be sent. IN the past there was hacks with for loops and new Date, but those loop holes were fixed.